# Why Kubernetes sets disk-pressure taint to my node?

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

How to figure out why the taint is set?

Here is my eviction config from kubelet config:

Kubelet-config:

```yaml
kubeletArguments:
  eviction-soft:
  - memory.available<100Mi
  - nodefs.available<100Mi
  - nodefs.inodesFree<1%
  - imagefs.available<100Mi
  - imagefs.inodesFree<1%
  eviction-soft-grace-period:
  - memory.available=1m30s
  - nodefs.available=1m30s
  - nodefs.inodesFree=1m30s
  - imagefs.available=1m30s
  - imagefs.inodesFree=1m30s
  eviction-hard:
  - memory.available<100Mi
  - nodefs.available<100Mi
  - nodefs.inodesFree<1%
  - imagefs.available<100Mi
  - imagefs.inodesFree<1%
```

`dh -f` output shows that there is 3.8GiB of 20GiB total space available. (>100Mi as configured), so neither soft nor hard eviction threshold is reached. `df -i` says only 20% of inodes used.

I've tried to figure out the reason by issuing `sudo journalctl -u kubelet -b | grep pressure` but found nothing useful. Maybe someone could suggest better keywords?

Comment: Is that the only filesystem? How many inodes are available (`df -i`)? Please post formatted code rather than screenshots. Screenshots break search, copy and paste, and are less accessible.

Comment: @BMitch, yes, this is the only one and only 20% of inodes used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resolved.
It turned out I used wrong syntax to configure thresholds. Here is correct way to set those:

```
evictionSoft:
  memory.available: "100Mi"
  nodefs.available: "100Mi"
  nodefs.inodesFree: "1%"
  imagefs.available: "100Mi"
  imagefs.inodesFree: "1%"
evictionSoftGracePeriod:
  memory.available: 5m
  nodefs.available: 5m
  nodefs.inodesFree: 5m
  imagefs.available: 5m
  imagefs.inodesFree: 5m
evictionHard:
  memory.available: "100Mi"
  nodefs.available: "100Mi"
  nodefs.inodesFree: "1%"
  imagefs.available: "100Mi"
  imagefs.inodesFree: "1%"
```

(config file is located at `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml` in my case)

Then kubelet needs to be restarted:
`sudo systemctl restart kubelet`

And here is a useful command to get kubelet logs to check if it started correctly: `journalctl -u kubelet --since "1min ago"`